# Creating a partition for 14.04 next to XP for dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, windows-xp

I was installing 14.04 and the only options I got were replace XP completely or something else. I choose something else. Partitions come up. Problem is I can't figure out how to create a new partition for 14.04 from here. I want to keep XP and install 14.04 as a dual boot option.

Comment: Look at this http://askubuntu.com/a/343370/265974 but the swap should at least your RAM size if you want to use hibernate. The /home partition is optional if you create only a root partition (/) the home folder will be saved at this partition also.

Comment: When you get it to work, the first time XP will say there is a disk error and want to do a disk check. This is because the drive space changed 'unexpectedly' when you changed partitions and installed Ubuntu. Don't Panic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing the same "wedding" between Windows XP and Ubuntu just in those days.
I had to reduce the window partition which was taking the whole disk, and i used the  under windows the software EaseUs.
EaseUIs  reduced the window partition, letting space for Ubuntu. Windows still does well

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I used it and installing now. Wonderful, simple help. Something Ubuntu needs.